# Remove an element from list inside a list in C#.

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a situation that my base list is consists with  **ConnectedUser** objects.

```
List<ConnectedUser> userList = new List<ConnectedUser>();
```

This is the ConnectedUser class :

```
public class ConnectedUser
{
  public string phone { get; set; }
  public HashSet<string> ConnectionIds { get; set; }
}
```

So how can I remove a specific **connectionId** from the list??

Comment: Firstly, it's a set, not a list - it's important to be aware of the difference. Now, do you already have the `ConnectedUser` associated with the `connectionId` you want to remove? If not, you'll have to look through *all* the users...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call remove in each set. It **will not** fail if there is no such connection id in the set.

```
string connectionId = "";
foreach (ConnectedUser user in userList)
    user.ConnectionIds.Remove(connectionId);
```

or

```
string connectionId = "";
userList.ForEach(u => u.ConnectionIds.Remove(connectionId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
userList.ForEach(o =>
    {
        var result = o.ConnectionIds.Except(c => c.ID == "idToBeRemoved");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this below:

```
foreach(var item in userList)
{
  item.ConnectionIds.Remove(x=>x.Id =="1")
}
```